# how to write sql subquery for same vale in name field and different id with multiple out put

Tags: mysql

I have on table below formate data in table.

```
PAGE_NAME | PAGE_ID| PRODUCT_ID 
test1     |001     |111 
test1     |002     |222 
test1     |003     |333 
test2     |004     |111
```

We need output:-

```
PAGE_NAME |PAGE_ID     |PRODUCT_ID 
test1     |001,002,003 |111,222,333 
test2     |004         |111
```

Please help.

any one idea??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this:

```
select page_name, 
       group_concat(page_id order by page_id) as page_id, 
       group_concat(product_id order by product_id) as product_id
from mytable
group by page_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function in mysql

```
SELECT PAGE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(PAGE_ID) PAGE_ID,GROUP_CONCAT(PRODUCT_ID) PRODUCT_ID
FROM table
GROUP BY PAGE_NAME;
```